# Reading low quality image barcode from scanner with zxing

Tags: java, image, image-processing, zxing

I recently decided to use a software to increase the productivity of my work, but I came across a problem, the scanners I have leave the images with a low quality.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6racI.png)

I would like to know what kind of image pre-processing would be more effective for zxing to be able to recognize the code and what other possible solutions to this problem.